# JavaScript: Object is causing bug?

Tags: javascript, html, object

I've been following [this video](http://youtu.be/9NrHPbudDpY) on how to make a platformer in JavaScript. Everything's been going fine up until this video. I've been able to make my sprite appear on a canvas, but when I was programming the keypress code, it stopped working; the HTML page went blank when I tried to run it. I've figured out which line is the problem, but I don't know how to fix it. Here's the HTML file:

```
<body onkeydown="keyDown(event)" onkeyup="keyUp(event)">
<canvas id="graphics" width=600 height=400 style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;"></canvas>

<script>
//VARIABLES
var gameCanvas = document.getElementById("graphics");
var grafx = gameCanvas.getContext("2d");
var player = new Object("Character1NoAA.png",100,100);
var img = new Image();
img.src = "Character1NoAA.png";
var isLeft = false;
var isRight = false;

//EVENTS
function keyDown(e) {
if (String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) === "%") isLeft = true;
if (String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) === "'") isRight = true;
}
function keyDown(e) {
if (String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) === "%") isLeft = false;
if (String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) === "'") isRight = false;
}

//MAINLOOP
MainLoop();
function MainLoop() {
//PRE VARIABLE ADJUSTMENTS
player.X += player.Velocity_X;
player.Y += player.Velocity_Y;

//LOGIC
if (isLeft) player.Velocity_X = -3;
if (isRight) player.Velocity_X = 3;
if (!isLeft && !isRight) player.Velocity = 0;

//POST VARIABLE ADJUSTMENTS
player.X += player.Velocity_X;
player.Y += player.Velocity_Y;

//RENDERING

grafx.clearRect(0,0,gameCanvas.width, gameCanvas.height);
grafx.drawImage(player.Sprite,player.X,player.Y);
setTimeout(MainLoop, 1000/60);
}

function Object(img,x,y) {
this.Sprite = new Image();
this.Sprite.src = img;
this.X = x;
this.Y = y;
this.Previous_X;
this.Previous_Y;
this.Velocity_X;
this.Velocity_Y;
}

</script>
</body>
```

I notice that, when I remove the `player.X += player.Velocity_X;` and `player.Y += player.Velocity_Y;` lines from the code (located under the `//PRE VARIABLE ADJUSTMENTS` comment), the picture appears just fine. What have I done wrong here? It's becoming very frustrating.

Comment: Check your browser console for JavaScript bugs

Comment: It appears the line `var player = new Object("Character1NoAA.png", 100, 100);` is creating a string. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/8XRYz/) fiddle...

Comment: Your code is hard to read without [indentation](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.Previous_X;
this.Previous_Y;
this.Velocity_X;
this.Velocity_Y;
```

These lines do nothing. It certainly does not define those properties. Therefore, when the "pre variable adjustments" code runs for the first time, it's trying to access undefined properties resulting in `NaN` coordinates.

Try:

```
this.Previous_X = this.X;
this.Previous_Y = this.Y;
this.Velocity_X = 0;
this.Velocity_Y = 0;
```

Comment: Do you mean I should rename the object at the bottom of the code to something else?

Comment: Consider prefixing it, like `function GameObject` instead. `Object` is the built-in core object that all other objects inherit from.